# Unicode error while creating directory in Flask-Admin

Tags: unicode, internationalization, flask, flask-admin

I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError` error with `FileAdmin` module (included in `Flask-Admin` library for Flask):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whenever I create a directory which has has non-ASCII characters in its name (like *très*), I get that error.

I think the point is to add UTF-8 encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but where (which files?) and how to handle this within `FileAdmin module`? This is unclear to me.

**Edit** following @PaoloCasciello request, find below the error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1701, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app 
response =  self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app 
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request 
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request 
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request 
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 59, in inner 
return f(self, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 59, in inner 
return f(self, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\contrib\fileadmin.py", line 460, in index
actions_confirmation=actions_confirmation)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 247, in render 
return render_template(template, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 125, in render_template 
context, ctx.app)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 107, in _render 
rv = template.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in render 
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception 
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\file\list.html", line 3, in top-level template code     
{% import 'admin/actions.html' as actionslib with context %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\master.html", line 1, in top-level template code 
{% extends admin_base_template %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\base.html", line 22, in top-level template code 
{% block page_body %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\base.html", line 40, in block "page_body" 
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\file\list.html", line 24, in block "body" 
{% block file_list_table %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\file\list.html", line 42, in block "file_list_table" 
{% block list_row scoped %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\file\list.html", line 51, in block "list_row" 
{% block list_row_actions scoped %}
File "C:\Flask\test\templates\admin\file\list.html", line 61, in block "list_row_actions" 
<input type="hidden" name="path" value="{{ path }}"></input>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\_native.py", line 22, in escape 
return Markup(text_type(s)
```

Comment: If you don't provide your code, there's not much we can help you with.

Comment: @Shervin: this is the `FileAdmin module` [code](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/flask/ext/admin/contrib/fileadmin/).... Of course this is not my code !

Comment: please provide the full traceback.

Comment: ok, edited my question according to @PaoloCasciello request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because Python `os.walkdir` returns filenames in ASCII when called with ascii path.

So, when you initialize FileAdmin, make sure you pass base path as unicode string::

```
admin.add_view(unicode(path), '/files/', name='Files')
```

Latest Flask-Admin has this fixed - FileAdmin will force unicode for the path internally.

Comment: By the way, I got the same problem when uploading files whose name contains non-ascii characters. What should I do in that case ?

Comment: I was doing a silly mistake...now I realize your answer works also for the upload of files. Thanks !